# PHP script to update the database

Tags: php

I have the following script the prints out the tables named host and notifier. The notifier table has a check box. I also have a submit button.

Now, How can this code update my database? If the user checks the checkbox in the notifier column, it should update the database with a Y, else leave it as the default value of NULL?

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");

mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");

$owner = $_GET['owner'];
$query = "SELECT `host`,`notifier` FROM `hosts` where `owner`='$owner'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";

$len = mysql_num_fields($result);

$tempString =  "<html><body><table border='2'><tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)

 {$tempString = $tempString.'<th>'.mysql_fetch_field($result)->name.'</th>';}

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

 {$tempString = $tempString.'</tr><tr>';

 foreach($row as $cell)

 {$tempString = $tempString.'<td>'.(($cell==null) ? '<input type="checkbox">Null</input>' : $cell).'</td>';}

 }

 $tempString = $tempString.'</td></tr></table></body></html>';

echo $tempString;

echo "</tbody></table><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>";
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Marc B That is fine. This is not production focused code. This is just to get input from server owners.

Comment: @KevinM That is not a good excuse.  Always right secure code and trust nobody, especially them evil server owners.

Comment: insert or update should work, but how do I get the submitted values when a user checks a check box and feed it to my update or insert statement?

Comment: There are many tutorials that cover that.  Not a good SO question - too broad, not specific to an issue.  Try something, if you get stuck ask something more specific and I am sure you will get help.  Best of luck,